# I can't get my environment variable to be recognized by my express javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, express, environment-variables

In my javascript file I am trying to place the key in an environment variable so I use this:

```
window.onload = function(){  
  (function getMap()
  {
    var locations = []; 
    var key = process.env.$BING 

   ....... an so on rest of code here
```

then in my bash .bash_profile I wrote

```
export $BING = "....key here...."
```

However process is not defined. How do I go about doing this as I have never done it before.

Comment: `process` doesn't exist in the browser. Are you using express as a web server to serve JavaScript files?

Comment: Then how do I store my key in an env variable ? or store it without committing it to github? I use a basic node server to serve the express that is rendering a map with ejs

Comment: You could use envify (https://github.com/hughsk/envify) in the postinstall hook or grunt/gulp task before deploying your app

Comment: I was able to get it working by passing the key from the backend (express) to the ejs template then I could use it by setting key to '<%=key%>' but now it says the key is invalid :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a super hacky solution. I passed the key in from the backend into the ejs. Then I set up a script to define a variable that I could use in the external js file. Then I used that variable as the string...whew...